# Dynamically Ignore property on writing object based on another property with System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, .net, system.text.json

I need to be able to serialize a class and ignore certain properties dynamically (not write them out into the JSON) if another property contains a certain value.

So image the following class:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public List<string> Types { get; set; }
    public string PropertyValidForType1 {get; set;}
    public string PropertyValidForType2 {get; set;}
    public string PropertyValidForType2 {get; set;}
}
```

If we have a string in the `Types` list of `Type1` I want the property to be serialized into the JSON string, same for `PropertyValidForType2` and `PropertyValidForType2`.

They'll be lots of properties that are not required to be serialized, so being able to do this with attribute would be beneficial. I understand it's possible to add `[JsonIgnore]` attribute but these don't allow conditionally ignoring properties.

Here's an example I'd like to get towards

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public List<string> Types { get; set; }

    [IncludeIfListIncludes(typeof(Types), "Type1")]
    public string PropertyValidForType1 {get; set;}

    [IncludeIfListIncludes(typeof(Types), "Type2")]
    public string PropertyValidForType2 {get; set;}

    [IncludeIfListIncludes(typeof(Types), "Type2")]
    public string PropertyValidForType3 {get; set;}
}

var c = new MyClass
{
    Types = new List<string> { "Type1", "Type3" },
    PropertyValidForType1 = "A",
    PropertyValidForType2 = "B",
    PropertyValidForType3 = "C",
}

var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(weatherForecast);

Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
// Expected Output: { Types : [ "Type1", "Type3" ], PropertyValidForType1: "A", PropertyValidForType3: "C" }
```

The above example would skip out `PropertyValidForType2` property because the list doesn't include a `Type2` within the list.

Comment: Can you explain, does Type property depends on values of other fields, or PropertyValidForType1/2/3 values depend on Types list?

Comment: @IvanKhorin PropertyValidForType1/2/3 depends on the certain type being in the Types list.

Answer (score 1):

I  couldn't sovle your problem as you wanted, this functionality looks to be not implemented in `System.Text.Json`, but you can make some pre-serialization manipulations with your object by implementing converter class derived from `JsonConverter()`.

```cs
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public static class Program
{
    public class IMyClassConverter : JsonConverter<MyClass>
    {
        public override MyClass? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            return null;            
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, MyClass value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();

            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value.Types);

            if (value.Types.Contains("Type1")) JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value.PropertyValidForType1);
            if (value.Types.Contains("Type2")) JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value.PropertyValidForType2);
            if (value.Types.Contains("Type3")) JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value.PropertyValidForType3);

            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public List<string> Types { get; set; }
        public string PropertyValidForType1 { get; set; }
        public string PropertyValidForType2 { get; set; }
        public string PropertyValidForType3 { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var c = new MyClass
        {
            Types = new List<string> { "Type1", "Type3" },
            PropertyValidForType1 = "A",
            PropertyValidForType2 = "B",
            PropertyValidForType3 = "C",
        };

        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
        options.Converters.Add(new IMyClassConverter());
        options.WriteIndented = true;

        var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(c, options);

        System.Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
    }
}
```

You have to dig this way, maybe create some `<T>` classes and so on, my busines logic is poor in this example but it works.
P.S. You can use interface, too, but I couldn't find like to realize that without casting object to interface.

```cs
// CODE
public interface IMyClass
{
    List<string> Types { get; set; }
    string PropertyValidForType1 { get; set; }
    string PropertyValidForType2 { get; set; }
    string PropertyValidForType3 { get; set; }
}

// ...
public class MyClass : IMyClass
// ...
IMyClass c = new MyClass
{
    Types = new List<string> { "Type1", "Type3" },
    PropertyValidForType1 = "A",
    PropertyValidForType2 = "B",
    PropertyValidForType3 = "C",
};
// ...
```